# Unable to traverse one-to-one relationship in Rails

Tags: relationship, ruby-on-rails-4

I've got an application where each user has one keyholder, who is allowed to access their account. These are separate models. I've set up the one-to-one relationship within the models, however when I try and use this within the views, I am getting the error of 'undefined method 'id' for nil:NilClass. I've used relationships and traversed them many times before, but I don't understand why this is happening, so please can someone explain?

The only thing that I have done differently from normal is to use Devise to generate the keyholder model rather than scaffolding it as I normally would.

Thanks!

user.rb:

```
has_one :keyholder
```

keyholder.rb:

```
belongs_to :user, dependent: :destroy
```

And neither of these views work:
keyholders/index.html.erb

```
<% @keyholders.each do |keyholder| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= keyholder.id %></td>
        <td><%= keyholder.username %></td>
        <td><%= keyholder.user.id %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', keyholder %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_keyholder_path(keyholder) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', keyholder, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
      </tr>
<% end %>
```

or keyholder/show.html.erb

```
<p>
  <strong>ID:</strong>
  <%= @keyholder.id %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Username:</strong>
  <%= @keyholder.username %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Keyholder for:</strong>
  <%= @keyholder.user.first_name %> <%= @keyholder.user.last_name %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>User ID:</strong>
  <%= @keyholder.user.id %>
</p>
```

Controller code:

```
  def index
    @keyholders = Keyholder.all
  end

  def show
    @keyholder = Keyholder.find(params[:id])
  end
```

Comment: What's the controller code that's creating `@keyholders` and `@keyholder`?

Comment: I've added it to the original question now. Thanks

Comment: Is it possible that there is no `Keyholder` in your database?  If you open Rails console, what does `Keyholder.all` return?  To clarify, are `Keyholder` and `User` both Devise models or is `Keyholder` the only Devise model.

Comment: They are both devise models - the user was scaffolded then devise was added, the key holder model was generated with devise. There is both a key holder and user in the database - if I remove any call to keyholder.user.foo, the error message disappears, and the keyholders display.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried everything to check where any errors could be - for example checking that both the keyholder's user_id and the user's keyholder_id were both integers etc.

In case anyone is reading this and wants the code to do so, it is:

```
@model.column_for_attribute('column_name').type
```

I didn't manage to fix this in the end - luckily I was just starting out with this app, so started again and scaffolded both models *before* adding Devise to them, and it now works fine having done everything else the same.